# how to force nethogs to fill/expand to the terminal width?

Tags: linux, terminal, ncurses, dynamic-columns

I am trying to make `nethogs` expand and fill any size I expand `xterm` or `konsole`, but with these, `nethogs` limit itself to show at most 80 characters columns width.
`nethogs` only fully expands while being run at `yakuake`.

In the other hand, `mc` is fully functional instantly expanding to any size, so it is not a ncurses issue.

So, I am trying to find a way to make nethogs believe terminal has a fixed width, so I can set it from the start and let it show more info. I believe ncurses can be configured (may be environment variables?) to believe terminal has a fixed width? I just cannot find how to do that.

newest nethogs install tip: https://askubuntu.com/a/729560/46437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in nethogs source-code which enforces the size.  The likely explanation is that your environment variables include `LINES` and/or `COLUMNS`, which a curses application will use to enforce screensize, by default.

`mc` can be built with ncurses or slang; slang tends to ignore those settings (a quick check of the code shows it uses them *only* if it cannot get a screensize in some other way).

Recalling a bug report from a year or so ago, bash, for instance, sets these *variables*, and some helpful packagers promoted those to environment variables: you may be using that.

Further reading:

- [use_env](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env) (manual page)
- [Handling SIGWINCH (resize events)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#handle_resize) (ncurses FAQ)

The comment about [ScriptEchoColor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptechocolor/files/Ubuntu%20.deb%20packages/) actually should be a separate question (since it was not mentioned).  If you look at `/usr/lib/ScriptEchoColor/utils/funcBase.sh`, line 1024, there are a few possible commands, one uncommented.  That reads

```
local lnTerminalWidth="`stty size 2>/dev/null |cut -d" " -f2`"
```

and determines the *current* screen width.  If it fails, it sets the variable to 80.  There is no provision for overriding it, and from the context of the question, it seems that this is probably executed once, for initialization.

Comment: I am actually trying to run this `secDelayedExec.sh -dx -s 60 --xtermopts "-geometry 210x70" sudo -k nethogs -v 3 -d 3` (so, together with it, I can delay many other initiallizations at ubuntu boot-up time, making many important to be ready fast apps available really fast).

Comment: That script is part of [scriptechocolor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptechocolor/files/Ubuntu%20.deb%20packages/), and it must be doing something that messes the way nethogs recognizes COLUMNS env var, or something else in that line. I think my best shot is try to output the columns nethogs is using, and determine what that script is messing. Thx on the tip! So I basically mean that, without that script, it actually works correctly with xterm and konsole... But still, with that script, `mc` works fine! that is puzzling me..

Comment: yes indeed, Initially I hadnt tried without that script, so I wasnt aware it could be the culprit. This question should be related about the problem originating on that script. Even if `mc` works with it, `nethogs` shouldnt fail with it. I think it is modifying something that it could avoid, or could provide a cleanse/revert method. thx!